# Custom ArcMap 10.3 Projections?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, coordinate-system, arcgis-10.3

I'm still pretty new to GIS, being a new EIT at a civil engineering firm. Im here to find out if ArcMap has this certain projection. If so, how do I access it?

In ArcMap the projection currently says "Lambert Conformal Conic". We need ArcMap to project to Lambert Conformal Conic with Affine Processor which would match our Microstation Coordinate System Properties.

Is there anyway to add this projection? I've attached an image to hopefully help.

[image: Microstation Coordinate System Menu]

Comment: Do the properties reference an affine or conformal transformation anywhere else? I'm a bit concerned that the "with Affine Processor" means that there's a second adjustment occurring on top of the Texas state plane zone. If there isn't, the projected coordsys definition will be in projected coordinate systems, state plane, NAD 1983 (US Feet).

Comment: I am not aware that you can set affine parameters for projections. ArcGIS also only supports custom transformation for geographic coordinate system this wouldn't help in your case since you would need to adjust the projected coordinates